# MySQL version error using prepared statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a prepared statement to protect my sql query from sql injection attacks. The statement was suggested in another post and I implemented it as indicated. I now get an error when the update query runs. It only occurs a few steps into my program. Here is a portion of the code and a commented area detailing the error. If I need to post the whole program let me know.

Here is the snippet:

```
    String updateQuery ="" + "   Update student" 
                + "Set  firstname = ?, " 
                + "     lastname = ?, " 
                + "     gpa = ? " 
                + "     status = ?, " 
                + "     mentor = ?, " 
                + "     level = ?, "
                + "     thesisTitle = ?, "
                + "     thesisAdvisor = ?, "
                + "     company = ?, "
                + "Where studentid = ? ";
            //This seems to work right up to set #7, then the program errors out. It indicates a syntax error that I cannot find?   
             // I wonder if the error is version dependant? Error points to MySQL version for correct syntax to use near '= ?,  that would be right after firstName.

        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(updateQuery); //to protect against SQL injection attacks
          pstmt.setString(1,firstName);
          pstmt.setString(2,lastName);
          pstmt.setDouble(3,gpa);
          pstmt.setString(4,status);
          pstmt.setString(5,mentor);
          pstmt.setString(6,level);
          pstmt.setString(7,thesisTitle);
          pstmt.setString(8,thesisAdvisor);
          pstmt.setString(9,company);
          pstmt.setString(10,studentID);

            int rowsInserted = stmt.executeUpdate(updateQuery);
        System.out.print("Number of Rows inserted = " + rowsInserted);      


        // Close the statement and the connection

        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

remove extra `comma` on the `company`

```
 + "     company = ?, "
                    ^ here
```

Comment: this happens normally due to *copy-and-paste* `:D`

Comment: I checked the online prepared statements syntax. There are no commas in either of the links. So I removed all of them. It did not change the problem.